# How can I append values to a dictionary where the keys has been initialized with none

Tags: python-2.7

My code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Chipsn():

      self.seq = [70, 80, 90, 100, 110]
      self.dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
      self.dict = {v: 0 for v in self.seq}

   def sort_func(self):
      """This is a private method that sorts the values in the list and then calls the 'avg_func' function to calculate and display the average datapoints."""

      self.sortd_datapoints = sorted(self.datapoints, key=lambda i: i[1])
      self.nfp_temp_data = [i[1:2] for i in self.sortd_datapoints]
      self.nfp_pow_data = [i[2:3] for i in self.sortd_datapoints]
      self.sys_pow_data = [i[3:4] for i in self.sortd_datapoints]
      self.core_pow_data = [i[4:5] for i in self.sortd_datapoints]

      self.avg_func(self.nfp_temp_data)
      self.avg_func(self.nfp_pow_data)
      self.avg_func(self.sys_pow_data)
      self.avg_func(self.core_pow_data)


   def avg_func(self, data_array):
      """This is a Private method -> Creates required keys and assign values to it. After this computes the average for the values in corresponding keys."""

      for i in data_array:
         if i[0] in self.dict.keys():
            self.dict[i[0]].append(i[0])
         else:
            (x, success) = self.in_range_func(i[0], self.dict.keys())
            if success:
               self.dict[x] = [i[0]]

      for x in sorted(self.dict.keys()):
         print self.dict[x]


   def in_range_func(self, curtemp, keys):
      """This is a Private method -> It decides the keys for the dictionary array"""      

      for k in keys:
         if (k-5) <= curtemp <= (k+5):
            return (k, True)
      return (curtemp, False)
```

The above is a snippet of a code and the data array looks like this

```
[[35.5], [41.5], [59.5], [70.0], [70.5], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.0], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [71.5], [90.0], [90.5], [90.5], [90.5], [90.5], [90.5], [90.5], [90.5], [90.5], [90.5], [90.5], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.0], [91.5], [91.5], [91.5], [91.5], [91.5], [99.5], [99.5], [99.5], [99.5], [99.5], [100.0], [100.0], [100.0], [100.0], [100.5], [101.0], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [101.5], [102.0], [102.0], [102.5], [102.5], [102.5], [102.5], [111.0], [111.0], [111.5], [111.5], [112.0], [112.0], [112.0], [112.0], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [112.5], [113.0], [113.0]]
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "list_of_dir.py", line 122, in <module>
    a.sort_func()

  File "list_of_dir.py", line 91, in sort_func
    self.avg_func(self.nfp_temp_data)

  File "list_of_dir.py", line 101, in avg_func
    self.dict[i[0]].append(i[0])

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What I want instead is the keys >> 70, 80, 90, 100, 110 being assigned values with an approximation of +-5

Comment: If you want to be able to append to the value - it has to be a list. So instead of doing `self.dict = {v: 0 for v in self.seq}` do: `self.dict = {v: [] for v in self.seq}`

Comment: @alfasin Thanks that helped :). and just wanted to confirm was the error due to the fact that the keys were initialized to 0 right? and is there any other possible way of doing it apart from using the list.

Comment: you can have the value as a string and perform a string-append - but I'm not sure if that's what you want. In this case using a list makes more sense.

Comment: @alfasin: yes you are right and also if i use str append then I have to apply split or to convert it to int to achieve what i really require. Thanks again :)